# RabbitMQ Spring template throws Attempt to use closed channel after sending 15 messages

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm trying out RabbitMQ for the first time and decided to go with the Spring AMQP wrapper.  I was planning to test the write performance first and set up a sender to a queue:

Spring setup:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" 
                           username="guest" password="guest" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:template id="myTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                 exchange="myQueue"/>
```

Sender Main:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                                             "th/rabbit-sender-context.xml");
    AmqpTemplate aTemplate = (AmqpTemplate) context.getBean("myTemplate");

    int total = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        aTemplate.convertAndSend("my.routingkey.1", "#"+i+" on "+new Date());
    }
```

However, after sending 15 messages, the client fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: clean connection shutdown; reason: Attempt to use closed channel
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:190)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:291)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:636)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:365)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.basicPublish(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:675)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$1.doInRabbit(RabbitTemplate.java:351)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:627)
... 9 more
```

How come?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what's closing the connection. I just ran an identical test with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your rabbit configuration.

Your amqp template 'myTemplate' is set with the exchange 'myQueue'.. is that ok? Are there any exchanges named 'myQueue', or this is your queue's name? If not, create an exchange then set that routing key to your desired queue.

If you set an invalid Exchange, no channels would be opened/acquired for your template, resulting in an AlreadyClosedException.